# unexpected SSH input_userauth_request: invalid user

Tags: ssh

We have a user that suddenly cannot log in via SSH on a Linux box. The error output in /var/log/secure is:

```
Invalid user foo from xx.xx.xx.xx

input_userauth_request: invalid user foo
```

Some additional details:

- The user has a shell correctly specified in /etc/passwd
- The user has a home directory with the correct permissions
- We made no changes to sshd_config, verified by the mod date
- No changes to user's .bashrc or .bash_profile
- The user cannot log in via password or key
- I've restarted sshd, and restarted the box
- The user's shell history shows no commands that might have caused this problem
- Ditto for root (used by only one person)
- VERBOSE output for sshd gives no other details
- No other user has this problem

I've done an extensive search, and have not found where else to look to identify the problem -- any insights would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `getent passwd foo` say?

Comment: Are you able to `login` as he using `su foo`?

Comment: Thanks for your replies:


# getent passwd foo

foo:x:32012:32013::/home/foo:/bin/bash


And I am able to su foo as well.

Comment: be aware, `auth.log`/journal do not quote the user name, if you see quotes, that means your user is trying to log in with a user-name that literally contains quotes. (for example in an .ssh/config user directive)

Answer (score 1):

A couple things you can check:

If you are using the AllowUsers directive make sure the IP/hostname matches what's defined in sshd_config.

If you are using hostnames instead of IP addresses with the AllowUsers directive verify the hostname reverses properly.

Comment: Thanks -- unfortunately I'm not using AllowUsers in sshd_config.

Answer (score -4):

It happened to me. It was because he was using a VPN. I had the exact same error. Exit the VPN if you have one.